# Sending a certain cell from the database to another PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am trying to send a specific cell to a PHP page and deleting that row which contains this specific cell. But it appears I am doing something wrong.

This is how I sending the information:

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id= '$row['pid']''>Delete</a>< /td>";
```

and using it like this:

```
$del = "DELETE FROM sca WHERE pid =  $_GET['id']";
```

My database connections are working well but I couldn't manage to send the 'pid' integer to a PHP page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you misstiped some character. Try with this :

```
        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['pid']."'>Delete</a></td>"; 
        echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$row['pid'].'">Delete</a></td>'; 
        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['pid']}'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Try to keep this code mixture (html and php) readable or improve it for future changes and revisions.

Make sure to receive correct value in `$row['pid']`.

Also as advice [you should protect your data and clean it before any db interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks, the first one you write is working and sending the value correctly. Do you have a solution for the delete operation that I made?

Comment: Typo again, the answer should be :
$del = "DELETE FROM sca WHERE pid='{$_GET['id']}'";